# Parsing JSOUP table

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-parser

I want to parse a table using **jsoup**. I have tried to get the flight data but without success!

My code is:

```
try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect("a.html").timeout(13 * 1000).get();
   Element table = doc.select("table.arrive-depart-table tbody tr").first();
   Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();
   Log.d("log", iterator.next().text());
}
```

and this is the html:

```
<table class="arrive-depart-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> string 1</td>
      <td> string 2</td>
      <td> string 3</td>
      <td> string 4</td>
      <td> string 5</td>
   </tr>
<tr>
<td> string 6</td>
...and more
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.select.Elements org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I am not able to parse the table flight.

Thank you

Comment: What is the question? Post url, expected output and current output. Also make sure that the html source contains the data with disabled JavaScript.

Comment: Hi i have edited 1st post

Comment: this `arrive-depart-table` class is fillup by javascript , so you need to use htmlunit driver or selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the background ajax call (check: chrome dev tools -> Network tab) and [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) to parse the response, it is possible to get the data without JavaScript:

**Example Code**

```
try {
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36";
    String url = "https://www.maltairport.com/wp-content/themes/mia/flightsinfo.php?arrivalsDepartures_action=getArrivalsDepartures";
    String referer = "https://www.maltairport.com/passenger/flights-landing/arrivals-departures/";
    String host = "www.maltairport.com";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).header("Host", host).header("Referer", referer).ignoreContentType(true).get();

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(doc.body().text());

    JSONArray arrivals = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("arrivals");
    JSONArray departures = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("departures");

    System.out.println("departures");

    for (Object object : departures) {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
        System.out.println("Flight: " + jsonObject.get("flightNumber") + "\n\t" + "To: " + jsonObject.get("airportName")
                + " SCH: " + jsonObject.get("scheduledTime") + " EST: " + jsonObject.get("estimatedTime") + " Status: " + jsonObject.get("remarks"));
    }

    System.out.println("\narrivals");

    for (Object object : arrivals) {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
        System.out.println("Flight: " + jsonObject.get("flightNumber") + "\n\t" + "To: " + jsonObject.get("airportName")
                + " SCH: " + jsonObject.get("scheduledTime") + " EST: " + jsonObject.get("estimatedTime") + " Status: " + jsonObject.get("remarks"));
    }

} catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Truncated Output**

```
departures
Flight: FR 7243
    To: DUBLIN SCH: 15:15 EST: 15:36 Status: AIRBORNE
Flight: LS 650
    To: EAST MIDLANDS SCH: 15:15 EST: 15:33 Status: AIRBORNE    
[...]

arrivals
Flight: KL 3399
    To: AMSTERDAM SCH: 14:50 EST: 14:56 Status: LANDED
Flight: KM 395
    To: AMSTERDAM SCH: 14:50 EST: 14:56 Status: LANDED
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you... You are the best!